# Django project structure for blog

Tags: python, django

Im new to django and im folowing many tutorial about django and every one of them have a different style and technique. my main focus is to structure my project for my django blog project. please help me to figure it out

Here are my question
Should i seperate the app for the example post, comment, categorie,tag, meta descriptions or just create the blog app and have all that model view in one app or i need to create the post, comment, categorie, tag, meta descriptions, and adding the frontend app to  handle the views and url.

if i have to seperate the the app that i mention above should the administrator for the dashboard area so the user can add post or delete in the app it self or i have to create the dashboard/administrator app.

Should i seperate the project for dashboard administrator with public page. or should their in same project but in deferent app.

i have done many schenario but one of the one i thing the best is. like this but i need aloot of comment about it

```
blog
--blog
--frontend
---- models.py model i leave it empty
---- views.py i focus handel the view of all blog app in here
---- urls.py urls so it make it easy to read and manage
--administrator
---- models.py model i leave it empty
---- views.py easy to set the validator decorator and anything
---- urls.py make the url easy to manage site/administrator if have to add post so it can be site/administrator/add-post
--posts
---- models.py
---- views.py
---- etc except urls.py
--categorie
---- models.py
---- views.py
---- etc except urls.py
--tag
---- models.py
---- views.py
---- etc except urls.py
--comment
---- models.py
---- views.py
---- etc except urls.py
--manage.py
--db.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

An app is a submodule of the project, it must be independent and focus on one task. So unless your project is very small, you should split it into multiple apps dependent on the logical parts of the blog: posts, comments, tags, users, categories, ... By dividing the project into various apps you avoid having huge files and gain in simplicity, reusability and elegance. Each app should contain its own models, views, forms and urls. Having a unique urls file doesn't make things easier, because you need to hard code the full path and it all gets chaotic quickly without organization. You should construct your frontend by putting each view in the right app and the associated templates in a unique directory. For administration, you can take advantage of the Django Admin that comes out of the box and simply include an `admin.py` file in each app (read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/) for details), but this type of administration should only be accessible to superusers. To allow normal users to make changes, you have to create views and templates in the associated apps. So compared to your current scheme I would remove the `administrator` and `frontend` app, I would create a `urls.py` file and a `admin.py` file for each app. For templates you can create a folder in each app or use a top level folder for all of them.

Comment: i see. sorry for delay because in a very hard to get signal. so if iwant make a blog app. i shuld seperate  the app just like you suggested. blog: posts, comments, tags, users, categories. oc tq.